# multivariate normal random numbers from Matlab to C#

Tags: c#, matlab, matrix, statistics, probability-theory

I am converting a code written on Matlab to C#.  In Matlab, there is a function called mvnrnd which is amultivariate normal random number generator.  This requires two inputs: n x d mean matrix and d-by-d cov matrix.  I googled and found math.net matrixnormal does do the same thing.

Unlike the function in Matlab, matrixnormal  requires three inputs: mean matrix (M), a cov matrix for the rows (V) and a cov matrix for the columns (K). The documentation states if the dimension of M is d-by-m then V is d-by-d and K is m-by-m.  I have these two inputs matrices (1x12 mean matrix and 12x12 cov matrixfor Matlab.  I would like to convert these two inputs into three inputs for matrixnormal.

Mean matrix part is not a problem but I don't know how to convert cov part.  I am not good at statistics.  Could someone help me to do this?  Thanks,

Comment: This seems to be a mathematical question rather than an programming issue. There is a simple way to transform a multivariate normal distribution into a matrix normal distribution, but it is only valid for diagonal matrices MU. I would ask this question at http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an elegant solution or anything, but I think it can work...

Why don't you create a covariance matrix by filling in the values, and then call ColumnCovariance() and RowCovariance() on it?  I've never written C#, so I don't know the syntax but this should give you a general idea:

```
Matrix covariance = new Matrix( [some numbers]) // basically just copy the covariance values
Matrix rowCov = covariance.getRowCovariance()
Matrix colCov = covariance.getColumnCovariance()
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer.  I also think it will work.  I just figured out that Accord.net has a class for this matter.  It works well and saved me time.  Again, thanks for your answer!!